# jQuery Select2 with spring and hibernate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, jquery-select2

I am using [Tag functionality of select 2](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html) in my spring application and hibernate to save it. I am using the AJAX call to save this form.
Till here it is working fine.

My problem is:

1. How can I populate the data from DB and display it in screen as tag so that user can update it. (this data has id and text)?
2. How can I save this data in DB using AJAX call. Basic form is saving but for this select2 data I am able to get only keys. I need proper Entity so that I can save/update it directly in DB?

an example will be very much appreciated. right now, I am not putting my code there. Please comment n this post if you want me to post any code.

FYI: I am new in spring and hibernate.

Comment: please tag "javascript". You are going to miss out on a lot of people that can help you.

Comment: Yeah, that's too bad. One problem you are going to have is that this question is much too broad. Generally, people come here for specific program-related problems or questions like "why doesn't this work?" or "why does javascript behave this way?". It is generally frowned upon to ask broad "how do I build _____ using javascript (or another language)". It would definitely be good to provide relevant code, in fact it is almost a requirement. Also, explaining what you have tried is good. Bottom line, this question has probably lost too much steam already.

Comment: ok I am creating a new question with specific details and code...may be that will help

Comment: Sounds good. Good luck and happy Easter!